# Returning Data From Express JS call (Using Fetch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm requesting data on my client from my database, but I'm unable to return the data when called. If I change the response method to `res.write()` my data is displayed on the page, but I need to return it into a variable instead as JSON. I've listed my server and client side code below.

Server Side Code:

```
    app.get('/t',function(req,res){

      var connection = mysql.createConnection({host:'*****', user: '****', password: '****', database: '****'});
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM  apron', function (err, results, fields) {
        res.json(results); // results contains rows returned by server
        connection.end(); 
});
```

Front-End Code (Fetch):

```
fetch('\t').then(function(result){
        return result.json();
    }).then(function(r){
        console.log(r);
    });
```

Comment: You surely meant `fetch('/t')`, not `fetch('\t')`? Check your server logs. I can't imagine what happens when you use a tab in an url…

Comment: So, what happens with your current code, what errors (exceptions) do you get (both on server and client side)? What does the network inspector tell you about the response, is it the expected result (and is the problem on the server or client side)? And what do you mean by "*I need to return it into a variable*"?

Comment: Lol, its crazy how an typo caused me pain. Go ahead and post your response as an answer so I can give you credit. @Bergi

Comment: Nah, just delete the post, it's not really worth to keep questions about typos.